# How to return the value from MySql Stored Proc?

Tags: mysql

I am using the below storedproc to generate the Insert statements of a specified table
It is build-ed without any errors. Now i want to return the result set in "V_string" as output of  the SP

```
    DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `demo`.`InsertGenerator` $$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `InsertGenerator`()
SWL_return:
BEGIN
-- SQLWAYS_EVAL# to retrieve column specific information

-- SQLWAYS_EVAL# table

   DECLARE v_string NATIONAL VARCHAR(3000); -- SQLWAYS_EVAL# first half

-- SQLWAYS_EVAL# tement

   DECLARE v_stringData NATIONAL VARCHAR(3000); -- SQLWAYS_EVAL# data

-- SQLWAYS_EVAL# statement

   DECLARE v_dataType NATIONAL VARCHAR(1000); -- SQLWAYS_EVAL# 

-- SQLWAYS_EVAL# columns

   DECLARE v_colName NATIONAL VARCHAR(50);
   DECLARE NO_DATA INT DEFAULT 0;
   DECLARE cursCol CURSOR  FOR 
   SELECT column_name,data_type FROM `columns`
   -- WHERE table_name = v_tableName;
   WHERE table_name = 'tbl_users';
   DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
   BEGIN
      SET NO_DATA = -2;
   END;
   DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET NO_DATA = -1;
   OPEN cursCol;
   SET v_string = CONCAT('INSERT ',v_tableName,'(');
   SET v_stringData = '';

   SET NO_DATA = 0;
   FETCH cursCol INTO v_colName,v_dataType;

   IF NO_DATA <> 0 then

      -- NOT SUPPORTED print CONCAT('Table ',@tableName, ' not found, processing skipped.')
close cursCol;

      LEAVE SWL_return;
   end if;

   WHILE NO_DATA = 0 DO
      IF v_dataType in('varchar','char','nchar','nvarchar') then

         SET v_stringData = CONCAT(v_stringData,'SQLWAYS_EVAL# ll(',v_colName,'SQLWAYS_EVAL# ''+');
      ELSE
         if v_dataType in('text','ntext') then -- SQLWAYS_EVAL# 

-- SQLWAYS_EVAL# else 


            SET v_stringData = CONCAT(v_stringData,'SQLWAYS_EVAL# ll(cast(',v_colName,'SQLWAYS_EVAL# 00)),'''')+'''''',''+');
         ELSE
            IF v_dataType = 'money' then -- SQLWAYS_EVAL# doesn't get converted 

-- SQLWAYS_EVAL# implicitly


               SET v_stringData = CONCAT(v_stringData,'SQLWAYS_EVAL# y,''''''+
isnull(cast(',v_colName,'SQLWAYS_EVAL# 0)),''0.0000'')+''''''),''+');
            ELSE
               IF v_dataType = 'datetime' then

                  SET v_stringData = CONCAT(v_stringData,'SQLWAYS_EVAL# time,''''''+
isnull(cast(',v_colName,
                  'SQLWAYS_EVAL# 0)),''0'')+''''''),''+');
               ELSE
                  IF v_dataType = 'image' then

                     SET v_stringData = CONCAT(v_stringData,'SQLWAYS_EVAL# ll(cast(convert(varbinary,',v_colName,
                     'SQLWAYS_EVAL# 6)),''0'')+'''''',''+');
                  ELSE
                     SET v_stringData = CONCAT(v_stringData,'SQLWAYS_EVAL# ll(cast(',v_colName,'SQLWAYS_EVAL# 0)),''0'')+'''''',''+');
                  end if;
               end if;
            end if;
         end if;
      end if;
      SET v_string = CONCAT(v_string,v_colName,',');
      SET NO_DATA = 0;

      FETCH cursCol INTO v_colName,v_dataType;

   END WHILE;


END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECT v_string.

Comment: @uriDium, i tried Select v_string; but not working. Still it says No result set returned